# connecting a String to a imageview

Tags: swift

So im building a random picture generator. and connecting a specific text string to a lable. Im wondering if this is the best way to do it, or if it could be a more effective way ?

just to be clear: this code works.

@IBOutlet var quote: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pictureframe: UIImageView!

```
var quotes = ["91": "Jepp,Jepp,JEPP!", "97": "nakenTORSDAG", "29P": "Løk"]
var picture = [UIImage]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 
    
    
    picture = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "29p"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "91"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "97"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "y"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_3105")]
    
}
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    

    
    pictureframe.image = bilder.randomElement()
    
    switch pictureframe.image {
    case UIImage(named: "91"):
        quote.text = quotes ["91"]
        
    case UIImage(named: "97"):
        quote.text = quotes ["97"]
        
    case UIImage(named: "29p"):
        quote.text = quotes ["29P"]
        
    default:
        quote.text = "HØR-HØR"
    }
    
    
    

    }







}
```

Comment: a little quick on the publish button there.  the reason im wondering is if i populate the image and quote variable  this method will be very stain-us to type out. and even add more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use random function better than this:

```
 func randRange (lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
       return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
   }
```

and then you can give it as an index to the dictionary:

```
var quotes = ["91": "Jepp,Jepp,JEPP!", "97": "nakenTORSDAG", "29P": "Løk","50P": "any","60F": "hi"]
let array = Array (quotes.keys)
func randRange (lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
       return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
   }
let number = randRange(lower: 0, upper: array.count - 1)
print(quotes[array[number]]!)
```

Comment: maybe im to new to this, but this would still require me to add an switch statement for each "quote" for each photo right ?